# Millions of Listings Mapped, 100gb of Data smoothly displayed, Advice

Tags: php, javascript, database, google-maps

I've been given a big project by a big client and I've been working on it for 2 months now. I'm getting closer and closer to a solution but it's just so insanely complex that I can't quite get there, and so I need ideas.

The project is quite simple: There is a 1mil+ database of lat/lng coordinates with lots of additional data for each record. A user will visit a page and enter some search terms which will filter out quite a lot of the records. All of the records that match the filter are displayed (often clustered) on a Google Maps.

The problem with this is that the client demands it's fast, lean, and low-bandwidth. Hence, I'm stuck. What I'm currently doing is: Present the first clusters, and when they hover over a cluster, begin loading in the data for that clusters children.

However, I've upped it to 30,000 of the millions of listings and it's starting to drag a little. I've made as many optimizations that I possibly can. When the filter is changed, I AJAX a query to the DB and return all the ID's of the matches, then update the map to reflect this.

So, optimization is not an option. I need an entirely new conceptual model for this. Any input at all would be highly appreciated, as this is an incredibly complex project of which I can't find anything in history even remotely close to it- I even looked at MMORPG's which have a lot of similar problems, and I have made a few, but the concept of having a million players in one room is still something MMORPG makers cringe at. It's getting common that people think there may be bottlenecks, but let me say that it's not a case of optimizing this way. I need a new model in which a huge database stays on the server, but is displayed fluidly to the user.

I'll be awarding 500 rep as soon as it becomes available for anything that solves this.

Thanks- Daniel.

Comment: So you can currently displaying 30k listings, and the goal is 1 million ? (Also, is it really ever useful for a user to be presented with even 30k things he can relate to/interact with  ?)

Comment: Yes. Upon first load, it displays several "groups" of listings with labels showing how many listings are inside the group. Hovering begins to load in it's children listings, clicking zooms in to see them. Searching is a case of sending the filters to the server, getting back a list of "id's", and making those markers/groups that are NOT on that list disappear. I pretty much need a miracle here, and I realise that. >_<

Comment: Where is the problem at ? Is the DB struggling because of complex queries (or you're using a non-GIS db to do GIS queries), is it the web server struggling because it needs to run complex algorithms, is it the browser where you're limited by slow javascript, non-optimal displaying ?

Comment: The client is struggling to handle the markers, and yet I need them to still SEE the markers. How do I show the client that which isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a number of possible answers to your question depending on where it is slowing down, so here goes a few thoughts.

A wider table can effect the speed with which a query is returned. Longer records mean that more disc is being accessed to get the right data, so you might want to think about limiting your initial table to hold only the information that can be filtered out. Having said that, it will also depend on the db engine you are using, some suffer more than others.

Ensuring that your tables are correctly indexed makes a HUGE difference in performance. You need to make sure that the query is using the indexes to quickly get to the records that it needs.

A friend was working with Google Maps and said that the API really suffered if too much was displayed on the maps. This might just be totally out of your control.

Having worked for Epic Games in the past, the reason that "millions of players in a room" is something to cringe at is more often hardware driven. In a game, having that number of players would grind the graphics card to a halt as it tries to render all the polygons of the models. Secondly (and likely more importantly) the problem would be that you have to send each client information about what each item/player is doing. This means that your bandwidth use will spike very heavily. Your server might handle the load, but the players internet connection might not.

I do think that you need to edit your question though with some extra information on WHAT is slowing down. Your database? Your query? Google API? The transfer of data between server and client machine?

Comment: Very good tips. As for performance- Nothing is lagging it. It's just conceptually slow.

Comment: @DanRedux Have you been able to time each step of the process from start to finish? I would be VERY surprised if one section of the chain wasn't bottlenecking the entire flow. If you can find out what is slowing down, you will be 90% of the way to solving the problem. I haven't come across many applications where more data meant that everything slowed down equally in a linear manner - there was always a bottleneck somewhere, either in a DB, a data transfer, the rendering capability of a machine or something.

Comment: I have done several benchmarks, yes. The database lookups have all performed to an expected level, and we are willing to throw as much hardware at it as necessary. The bottlenecks are filtering the data and generating the "clusters", even though we are currently using some of the best clustering methods possible and all filtering is done server-side. I guess you could say the client is the bottleneck, as it has to deal with thousands and thousands of markers.

Comment: @DanRedux I take it you have done some reading on the google maps API and the number of markers? http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/ Short Version is Lots==Bad!

Comment: Yes, hence the clustering. We group up markers into groups and only display the ones in the viewport. Point is, 1mil records in the Clients Memory alone is enough to cripple our average user... It's definitely not a lack of optimization, I'll tell you that much.

Comment: @DanRedux "I need a new model in which a huge database stays on the server, but is displayed fluidly to the user." You have to limit the amount of data being sent to the client machine. Have you tinkered with the size of the clustering in terms of bigger/smaller result sets? Can you perhaps limit the zoom at which Google Maps is still rendering the markers? Can a cluster spawn other clusters? Also, have you looked at MarkerLight.js by Pamela Fox?

Comment: I did look up MarkerLight, but it didn't speed it up much, as it still takes up a considerable amount of memory. I started with every action querying the server, then started to pre-load and cache more and more until there was a nice balance. Optimizing, at this point, would be more of a band-aid fix.

However, I had an idea. What if I maintain the DB server-side, but upon any change, transmit all of the data that the user should see EXCEPT for what they are already seeing? Progressively replace their screen, use similar techniques from video streaming? I can throw hardware at the server...

Comment: Sending a delta of the information required would certainly speed the process up. You could also look at sending the data incrementally so that the client machine doesn't have to manage a large chunk at a time, but rather processing it in smaller sections. Maybe even put a "Loading..." style progress bar. Users are MUCH more patient when they can see something is ticking along. A twenty second wait with no progress bar seems an eternity, while the same wait with a progress bar seems like a complex action is taking place.

Comment: Sadly, the client refuses to have any loading bars. :( 
I was going to compress the important parts of the data down and have a loading bar while it downloads, about 8mb in total, then it would run a lot faster. They wouldn't have it. :P

Comment: So paginate it? Good idea, I've been avoiding that thinking it would look bad but it may not.

Comment: Aside from paginating it, I came across this site ages ago, should have mentioned it earlier. This might be a good way for you to display huge datasets on the maps API. https://queenslandfloods.crowdmap.com/ It works very quickly and can display a large resultset in pretty much real time.

Comment: Very useful link, it gives me a good look at the "competition" so to speak. Thanks.

Comment: How did you go with that approach to displaying the data on gMaps? Their response time is fantastic and they are displaying data from thousands of records, but grouping it in a brilliant yet simple method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest here; a db with 1 million records being accessed by presumably a large amount of users, is not going to run very well unless you put some extremely powerful hardware behind it.

In this type of case, I would suggest using several different database servers, and setting up some decent load balancing regimes in order to keep them running as smoothly as possible. First and foremost, you will need to find out the "average" load you can place on a db server before it starts to lag up; let's say for example, this is 50,000 records. Setting a low MaxClients per server may assist you with server performance and preventing against crashes, but it might aggravate your users when they can't execute any queries due to high load.. but it's something to keep in mind if your budget doesn't allow for much wiggle room hardware-wise.

On the topic of hardware however, that's something you really need to take a look at. Databases typically don't use a huge amount of CPU/RAM, but they can be quite taxing on your HDD. I would recommend going for SAS or SSD before looking at other components on your setup; these will make the world of a difference for you.

As far as load balancing goes, a very common technique used for most content providers is that when one query/particular content item (such as a popular video on youtube etc) is pulling in an above average amount of traffic, you can cache its result. A quick and dirty approach to this is to use an if statement in your search bar, which will then grab a static html page instead of actually running the query.

Another approach to this is to have a seperate db server on standalone, only for running queries which are taking in an excessive amount of traffic.

With that, never underestimate your code optimisation. While the differences may seem subtle to you, when run across millions of queries by thousands of users, those tiny differences really do add up.

Best of luck with it - let me know if you need any further assistance.

- Eoghan

Comment: Load balancing and caching are great tips, but in this situation it's not a performance issue so much as a conceptual issue. No matter how much hardware and money is thrown at this, the current model lags the USER (over which I have no control). I need a way to present this much data interactively to the user, with filtering, plotting on a map, clustering by distance, etc. It's the conceptual model that I need help with. Thank you, though, any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a service named "Big Query". It is a sql Server in the cloud. It uses its fast servers for sql and it can search millions of data rows quickly. Unfortunately it is not free.. but maybe it will help you out:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/

Comment: Very good link, however, I can optimize things as much as they need, get in as much hardware as I need, etc. It's simply the conceptual stuff- This needs to be displayed smoothly and interactively to the user, and that's the part I'm having trouble with.